# Running fewer unit tests on build?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, build-server

I was wondering and have looked about for a potential solution to our build becoming increasingly long based on how slow our Jest tests are becoming. In the grand scheme of things to run all of our test takes on average around 22-24 mins depending on the load across all of our VMs.

What I was looking for was a way to only run the test in the changed files relating to the PR in question. I wasn't and currently am unsure if this is possible. I have seen locally you can do so by running against all untracked files but that's not really an option once it's being tested on the servers.

Comment: That's not a good idea. The point of running the tests in a build environment is to make sure that *everything* is working correctly (i.e. you haven't introduced any regressions), and you weren't seeing false positives due to some state on your local machine. Focus on speeding up the test suite instead.

Comment: We shallow render all of our components so if a component didn't change there should be no reason to suspect regression will be found surely?

Comment: Probably, and you would certainly hope so, but if you were wrong you'd definitely want to know! FWIW I don't think a lot of very granular shallow rendering is a path to high-quality tests, you end up making it harder to confidently refactor and improve your code (see e.g. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering for more arguments).